# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass on find_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code here:

```
if hotel_hash[:postal_code].present?
  selected_hotel = @hotels.find_all { |hcom| hotel_hash[:postal_code].to_s.gsub(/\s+/, "") == hcom[:postal_code].to_s.gsub(/\s+/, "") }
end
```

`@hotels` is populated. An error is raised on the `selected_hotel` line. I've gone through on a byebug and it works up until this postal code: `S7 1NQ`. Any ideas would be great.

Comment: Any chance you have a `nil` in your `@hotels`?

Comment: Please post the complete error message including the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have at least one`nil` value in your `@hotels` enumerable.

You might want to `@hotels.compact` before filtering the list:

```
selected_hotel = @hotels.compact.find_all { |hcom| hotel_hash[:postal_code].to_s.gsub(/\s+/, "") == hcom[:postal_code].to_s.gsub(/\s+/, "") }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, hotel_hash is present, I attempted both the above and it hasn't worked, returning the same thing still

Comment: And ive made sure that in @hotels, the postal_code is populated before being pushed to the var

Comment: @Sam I am sorry, I missed something. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Sam No, `hotel_hash` is not the issue. What spickermann (and  Marcin Kołodziej in the comment) are saying is that `hcom` is `nil`.